# How do write a function/macro to wrap arbitrary interactive function?

Tags: functions

I'm trying to write a function/macro to wrap arbitrary interactive function with some pre- and post- processing. Those processing does not involve the arguments of the interactive function.

For example, give f = `delete-region`, I'd like to write a function/macro that return a new function g = `delete-region-wrapper` with the definition like

```
(defun delete-region-wrapper (begin end) # or maybe (&rest args)...
    (interactive "r")
    (read-only-mode -1) # 'pre-processing'
    (delete-region begin end) # or maybe (apply #'delete-region ...) or maybe (funcall #'delete-region ... ) 
    (read-only-mode 1)) # 'post-processing'
```

Or the Python equivalent looks like

```
def wrap(f):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        read_only_mode(-1)
        res = f(*args, **kwargs)
        read_only_mode(1)
        return res
    
    return wrapper

 delete_region_wrapper = wrap(delete_region)
```

How can I write this `wrap` macro/function?

```
(defmacro/defun wrap(f)
    ???
)

(setq delete-region-wrapper (wrap #'delete-region))
```

Comment: You should `let`-bind `inhibit-read-only` instead of switching `read-only-mode` off and on.  Aside from anything else, switching modes like that would require you to also do error-handling in order to ensure that you ended up in the correct state even if something went wrong in the code you were wrapping (notwithstanding that your example wasn't actually checking the pre-existing state at the beginning).

Comment: @phils You are right! Thanks for the insight!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to return a lambda, since functions are first class members of the language.

```
(defun wrapper (f)
  (lambda (beg end)
    (interactive "r")
    (read-only-mode -1)
    (apply f (list beg end))
    (read-only-mode 1)))
```

Above will create a function object with a closure (`f` is fixed in this closure).
Then assign the returned function object into the function-slot of a symbol (e.g. `w-d-r`):

```
(setf (symbol-function 'w-d-r) (wrapper #'delete-region))
```

or

```
(fset 'w-d-r-2 (wrapper #'delete-region))
```

Above example is fixed to wrapping functions with two arguments, whose rely on region borders. It is possible to abstract more, by using `&rest args` as parameters, then your call to [`interactive`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Using-Interactive.html) needs to become more complex and instead of `(list beg end)` you would supply `args` to `apply`.

```
(defun wrapper (f)
  (lambda (&rest args)
    (interactive (SOMETHING-FANCY-HERE))
    (read-only-mode -1)
    (apply f args)
    (read-only-mode 1)))
```

**Edit:** instead of using apply, a call of `call-interactively` might suffice:

```
(defun wrapper-2 (f)
  (lambda () 
    (interactive)
    (read-only-mode -1)
    (call-interactively f)
    (read-only-mode 1)))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that works! I have one more question, what if I also want to pass the pre- post-processing body (maybe multiple sexp for each) to `wrapper-2`? Do I need a macro then?

Comment: you mean you want to replace `(read-only-mode ..)` with some other function? It still works with a function. Wrapper-2 would take more parameters like `f1` and you would call those functions via `apply` or `call-interactively`. Of course it would be possible to write a macro, but one should prefer a function if a function would do.

Comment: Thanks for the hint!